# Recycler Viiew not working in MainActivity.kt in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

[Although I have installed all the dependencies i.e. implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1' implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0' Still my recycler view is not working Can someone please help me out in this like where I'm going wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EDIs.png)

Comment: Kotlin Andorid extension i.e. synthetic import is deprecated and you need to use view binding or data binding. please follow the link for more info:  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: You haven't made a RecyclerView object.